# SCCM cmdlet from a remote PC

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm trying to create a script to query members of a sccm2012 device collection so that I can pipe that into put into maintenance window. I need to run this from a remote machine.

Here's what I have - if I run each line by line it works fine.
But if I run it as a script continuously fails. If you could point me in the right direction please or solve for me. PS I'm not that good at PS but getting better.

```
PS F:\Install\Scritps> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName SERVER -ConfigurationName Microsoft.PowerShell32

Import-module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1"

cd P01:\

Import-module : The specified module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1' was not loaded because no 
valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:4 char:1
+ Import-module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConso ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\Program File...ionManager.psd1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

cd : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'P01' does not exist.
At line:6 char:1
+ cd P01:\
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (P01:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that the sccm modules are only supposed to work in 32bit powershell. Could it be that you run them one by one after starting the x86 powershell, but run the script directly from the file which would probably lead to it being interpreted with the native 64bit powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that `Enter-PSSession` fails becauase it is designed for interactive use, and not to be used in a script. If that fails, then the following commands would fail because you're missing the SCCM 2012 Admin Console.

To run remote commands in a script, use `Invoke-Command`. Combine it with `New-PSSession` if you need a special configuration, different credentials etc.

```
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName SERVER -ConfigurationName Microsoft.PowerShell32

Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {

    Import-module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1"

    cd P01:\

    gci
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Powershell Equivalent to Query in SCCM UI

I'm guessing you'd like to script the same queries as SCCM allows you to specify in this device collection query rules property dialog box:

[image]

The most reliable way to run such a query on an SCCM server from powershell on a workstation is using CIM.  The trick is figuring out how to run the query so that it is interpreted in exactly the same way as if SCCM itself runs the query.  Doing it this way seems to achieve that goal:

```
$SiteCode       = 'ST1'    # replace this with your SCCM site code
$SccmServerName = 'sccm01' # replace this with your server name

# replace this with your query
$query = @'
select 
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System 
inner join 
    SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM 
    on SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId 
where 
    SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Manufacturer like "%Microsoft%"
'@

$params = @{
    ComputerName = $SccmServerName
    Query        = $query
    NameSpace    = "Root\SMS\Site_$SiteCode"
}

Get-CimInstance @params
```

The query above happens to be for a device collection of Hyper-V guests .  You can change `$query` to whatever you want.  Once you get the query working here, you should be able to copy and paste it to/from the SCCM device colleciton UI.

#### On Powershell Remoting

If the call to `Get-CimInstance` results in an error that indicates that Powershell remoting or CIM is not working in your case, then you should probably focus on understanding that aspect of your environment.  Powershell remoting has some nuanced limitations and prerequisites that depend, among other things, on firewall settings, enabling remoting, and what version of Powershell and operating systems you're running.  It's not worth remembering all the details.  The reference I use is Chapter 10 of [Powershell in Depth, second edition](http://www.manning.com/jones6/).

If it turns out you must use WMI instead of CIM, it should be fairly straightforward to translate the call to `Get-CimInstance` to `Get-WmiObject`.

Comment: CIM/WMI is an efficient solution, but an official SDK should almost always be recommended when it can solve the problem as that is what the vendor will support if you experience any bugs. Also, it's cleaner to work with. His problem (creating maintenance windows) can be solved using `Get-CMDeviceCollection`, `New-CMSchedule` and `New-CMMaintenanceWindow`

Answer (score 0):

Frode F. you are the man

yep it works real good.

at the end after the } i put "Remove-PSSession -ComputerName SERVER"

so that when you run it a few times the concurrent session fill up. with this extra line no worries.

Comment: Glad it worked. Just FYI, comments should not be submitted as an answer, but by using "add a comment" below the related answer. Also, remember that maintenance windows are defined on collections, so you don't need to retrieve the devices inside a collection, but simply add the schedule to the collection itself using `Get-CMDeviceCollection`, `New-CMSchedule` and `New-CMMaintenanceWindow` (2012 R2).